# preg_replace with attribute values

Tags: php, preg-replace

Im using preg_replace to decode bbcode and i use `(.*?)` to get the attribute values.

I want to replace it with `font-size:\10px; (font-size:(.*?)0px;)` so that for example if the attribute value is 7 then the font size would be 70. but instead it thinks that i want the value \10. What can i do to separate the attribute value and the 0?

Is it possible to do like `'font-size:'.\1.'0px;'` or something similar to separate the attribute value from the zero?

Comment: Post sample inout and your preg_replace call.

Comment: preg_replace call = `'/\[size\="?(.*?)"?\](.*?)\[\/size\]/ms'`

replace with = `'<span style="font-size:\\${1}0px">\\2</span>'`

sample output = `<span style="font-size:70px;">blalba</span>` (assuming value is 7)

Comment: Pls provide a sample input so that I can try your sample and suggest you something.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`\${1}0` is the solution as documented [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php).

[edit]

I tried all possible amounts of backslashes and have to say.. to me it makes absolutely *no* sense, that

```
echo preg_replace('/(2.)/', '\\${1}', '12345');
```

outputs `1${1}45`

But I have found one solution, [heredoc](http://www.php.net/manual/de/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc):

```
$a = <<<ABC
\${1}
ABC;
echo preg_replace('/(2.)/', $a, '12345');
```

Comment: `'<span style="font-size:\${1}0px">\2</span>'` i have tried this but it outputs `<span style="font-size:${1}0px">`

Comment: It should be `'<span style="font-size:\\${1}0px">\\2</span>'`

Comment: doesn't seem to work, acts just like it would with a single backslash

Comment: Strange PHP behavior abount backslashes. Compare PHP to C (or other famous languages). [PHP] http://ideone.com/rU9lxQ  [C] http://ideone.com/lCBEGQ

Comment: @Matmarbon Alright seems i got a different output this time atleast, the output with 3 backslashes became `font-size:\70px;'

Comment: @Matmarbon `\\\$` makes confusion. It should be `\\\\$`.

Comment: @CertaiN Still outputs `font-size:\70px;` with 4 backslashes

Answer (score 1):

Apply to this text:

```
$str = <<< EOD
[size="4"]test1[/size]
[size="4]test2[/size]
[size=4"]test3[/size]
[size=4]test4[/size]
EOD;
$pattern = '@\\[size=("?)(\\d++)\\1\\](.*?)\\[/size\\]@s';
```

preg_replace:

```
$replace = '<span style="font-size:${2}0px;">$3</span>';    
echo preg_replace($pattern,$replace,$str);
```

preg_replace_callback:

```
$replace = function ($matches) {
    return sprintf('<span style="font-size:%s0px;">%s</span>',
        $matches[2],
        $matches[3]
    );
};     
echo preg_replace_callback($pattern,$replace,$str);
```

Result:

```
<span style="font-size:40px;">test1</span>
[size="4]test2[/size]
[size=4"]test3[/size]
<span style="font-size:40px;">test4</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Omg... PHP manual makes a big confusion...

About this code:

```
echo preg_replace('/^(1)(2)(3)(4)(5)$/', $r, '12345');
```

Expected output:

```
12345!!12345!!
```

When using heredoc:

```
$r = <<< EOD
$0!!\${1}2\${3}4$5!!
EOD;
```

However, not using heredoc:

```
$r = '$0!!${1}2${3}4$5!!';
```

Yes, **backslashes are unneeded**.